# Object named could not be found

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, object

I am using ArcMap 10.8, and whenever I try to add vector or raster data I found this message:

> the object named could not be found

I see this message with data stored on a UNC path

Why do I get this error?

[image: my add data problem]

Comment: Do you see this message with any data stored locally and not on a UNC path?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response .... I see this message with data stored on a UNC path